What does わけではなかったのか exactly mean?

今日はどうしてここに？
ユリコ: どうして。そうだな、あの後が気になった
とはいえユリコはあれから何かをしていたわけではなかったのか。
言い方は荒いが数日眠って、また起きてこに来た。

I understand わけではなかった but then why is のか  added? What does it add? The character asks her why she came and she says I was curios.
Then the narration added "It's not like she did anything after that? Phrasing, she jsut slept and then woke up and came here"?

のか adds the nuance that speaker realized something, possibly with surprise ("Oh, ...", "So, ...", "..., huh?"). This の is an explanatory-no, and this か is more of an exclamation marker rather than a question marker.
Compare:

これは鍵なのだ。
(It's that) this is a key.
これは鍵なのか。
Oh, so this is a key!
I see, this is a key!
(The fact that it's a key explains something)
これは鍵か。
Hm, this is a key, huh?
(The speaker learned it's a key, but doesn't know what it means)

